# Magento 2: Get extension attributes data before customer address is saved

Tags: magento2, event-observer, extension-attributes

We have created an extension attribute which we would be accepting via customer address REST API

Endpoint: PUT `customers/:customerId`

Request body:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "firstname": "test",
    "lastname": "test",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "region": {
          "region_code": "NY",
          "region": "New York",
          "region_id": 43
        },
        "country_id": "US",
        "street": [
          "Address1",
          "Verified"
        ],
        "firstname": "test",
        "lastname": "test",
        "default_shipping": false,
        "default_billing": true,
        "telephone": "8600360471",
        "postcode": "98761",
        "city": "New York",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "verification_status": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Created an observer on `customer_address_save_before` however the following returns null: `$customerAddress->getExtensionAttributes();`

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
    $verificationStatus = $customerAddress->getExtensionAttributes();
}
```

I need to fetch the extension attribute to save it to the customer address via REST API

There is also a custom attribute created but that too is coming as null when passed via REST API

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly declared the extension attributes via `extension_attributes.xml`? You will have to declare `verification_status` along with the expected type for `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` if you haven't already.

More info can be found here:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html#extension-attributes-configuration